# How to Make return value of function for legend

Tags: r, function

I made a function that plots data from a csv file.

I would like to get the labels in the legend from names of variables used when I call the function.

With the code below, `names(dataPlot1)` uses the names "temp1" "temp2" "temp3" in the legend. I want to make it "x","y","z". How can I do this?

```
temperature <- function(temp1,temp2,temp3)
{
    dataPlot1 <- data.frame(temp1,temp2,temp3)
    matplot(dataPlot1,axes=T,frame=T,type="l",
            xlab="time (hour)",ylab="temperature(C)",
            main=names(dataPlot1))
    lines(dataPlot1[1],lty=1,col="blue")
    lines(dataPlot1[2],lty=2,col="red")
    lines(dataPlot1[3],lty=2,col="forestgreen")  
    legend("topright",names(dataPlot1),lty=c(1,2,2),
            col=c("blue","red","forestgreen"))

}
temperature(x,y,z)
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this :

```
temperature <- function(temp1,temp2,temp3)
{ t1 <- deparse(substitute(temp1))
  t2 <- deparse(substitute(temp2))
  t3 <- deparse(substitute(temp3)) 
    dataPlot1 <- data.frame(temp1,temp2,temp3)
    matplot(dataPlot1,axes=T,frame=T,type="l",
            xlab="time (hour)",ylab="temperature(C)",
            main=names(dataPlot1))
    lines(dataPlot1[1],lty=1,col="blue")
    lines(dataPlot1[2],lty=2,col="red")
    lines(dataPlot1[3],lty=2,col="forestgreen")  
    legend("topright", c(t1,t2,t3), lty=c(1,2,2),
            col=c("blue","red","forestgreen"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several options:

1. Name your data:  `dataPlot1 <- data.frame(x=temp1, y=temp2, z=temp3)`
2. Assign names later:  `colnames(dataPlot1) <- c("x", "y", "z"))
3. Supply the desired text as `legend=` argument to the `legend()` call.
4. Change your function and add a fourth argument, say `legtxt=c("x","y","z")` and pass that to `legend`.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the question (and hence edited it poorly) but I thought the OP wanted to access the names of the variables passed to the function from within the function itself. i.e. `temperature(foo,bar,foobar)` would label the legend with "foo", "bar" and "foobar" without hard coding that into the function body.

Comment: Option one still works if you pass a data.frame *with names* in. The names info has to come from somewhere...  I added a fourth option.  But you cannot autoMAGICally assign names in a legend if the data does not have names attached.

Comment: Ok, yeah. Changing the function to accept a single data frame with all three variables is probably preferable to using `get` in some fashion. :)